# Warning in equation

Tags: equations, warnings, auxiliary-files, subequations

I had inserted these equations:

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}   
        \rho(\bm{z}) = \bm{z}; 
        \label{eq.:Rho(z)=z} \\
        \bm{x}(\bm{z}) = \epsilon + (1 - \epsilon){\bm{z}}^p, & \quad \text{for } p \geqslant 1
        \label{eq.:SIMP}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
    \overline{\bm{z}} = \frac{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(\bm{z} - \eta\right)\right)}{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(1 - \eta\right)\right)}
    \label{eq.:HeavisideFnc}
\end{equation}
```

And I got this warning message with no info:

[image: Warinig Message]

I am using these two packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{bm}
```

There is these warning in the log. file:

```
Chapter 3.
<Imagens/Design_Domain.pdf, id=754, 262.73157pt x 184.43906pt>
File: Imagens/Design_Domain.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use Imagens/Design_Domain.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Imagens/Design_Domain.pdf used on input line 13.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 210.18552pt x 147.55144pt.
 [26

 <./Imagens/Design_Domain.pdf>] [27pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the 
same identifier (name{equation.3.2.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

    \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                      \fi \fi 
    l.51 
         ] <Imagens/SIMP.pdf, id=800, 392.96812pt x 322.95656pt>
    File: Imagens/SIMP.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

    <use Imagens/SIMP.pdf>
    Package pdftex.def Info: Imagens/SIMP.pdf used on input line 54.
    (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 392.96715pt x 322.95576pt.
    pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.3.2.
    2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
    <to be read again> 
                       \relax 
    l.63 \begin{equation}
                          [28 <./Imagens/SIMP.pdf>]
```

The '.log' file says I have inserted the same equations twice, but I didn't.

[image: Equation]

As one can see, equation.3.2.1 is the first equation of this file created using `subequations` package in the subsection 3.2.1 of my `.tex` file and the equation.3.2.2 is the second equation of it.
In section 3.2.2 I define another equation, which is also the labeled as equation.3.2.2, causing this warning in latex.

Finally, the `.aux` file has this:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}Material Model}{27}{section.3.2}}
\newlabel{sec.:Model}{{3.2}{27}{Material Model}{section.3.2}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}Solid Isotropic Material with Penalization (SIMP)}{27}{subsection.3.2.1}}
\newlabel{subsec.:SIMP}{{3.2.1}{27}{Solid Isotropic Material with Penalization (SIMP)}{subsection.3.2.1}{}}
\newlabel{eq.:Rho(z)=z}{{3.1a}{27}{Solid Isotropic Material with Penalization (SIMP)}{equation.3.2.1}{}}
\newlabel{eq.:SIMP}{{3.1b}{27}{Solid Isotropic Material with Penalization (SIMP)}{equation.3.2.2}{}}
\citation{Leitao_et_al2018}
\citation{Lahuerta2012}
\citation{Lahuerta2012}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.2}Heaviside Projection Function}{28}{subsection.3.2.2}}
\newlabel{subsec.:Heaviside_Fnc}{{3.2.2}{28}{Heaviside Projection Function}{subsection.3.2.2}{}}
\newlabel{eq.:HeavisideFnc}{{3.2}{28}{Heaviside Projection Function}{equation.3.2.2}{}}
```

I had tried to fix this, but I didn't found how. 
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code which reproduces the problems, not snippets?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error, but it only happens in my case, which is a very big code

Comment: But what does the warning say?

Comment: Nothing!! It's exactly as in the figure! It does not inform the line or the type. @Bernard

Comment: And in the .log file?

Comment: off-topic but `tanh` wouldn't really look nice, you should probably declare a new operator. Try `\DeclareMathOperator{\tanh}{tanh}` in the preamble and then you can use `\tanh` and it will look like `tan` and `sin` and `cos` and all the rest

Comment: Actually ignore that and just use `\tanh` I think it comes free, but I do know some of them don't

Comment: I updated the post with .log file @Bernard

Comment: I did not realize that. Thanks @Au101

Comment: Can you compile with the equation uncommented? With a simpler equation? With half of your equation? You do need to pin point exactly where the problem is - and then create a MWE(Minimal (non-)Working Example).

Comment: Yes @hpekristiansen. I tried to compile eliminating pieces os it and the problem still the same, it only disappears when I delete the equation

Comment: Do you by any chance have a duplicate `\label` instruction? I.e., is there a `\label{eq.:HeavisideFnc}` instruction somewhere else in the document as well?

Comment: No, I don't. @Mico

Comment: There must be a lot more going on in your document, of which you have revealed very little so far. The log file makes it look like you're using either the `graphics` or the `graphicx` package. Is this impression correct? Do you load packages such as `hyperref` and/or `cleveref`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `graphicx` and `hyperref`. @Mico

Comment: your warning clearly stated that you have two labels which are  the same. since with given code snippet we cant reproduce your problem (it works fine), we can't further help you.

Comment: @Zarko where in that log do you see anything about two labels with the same name? It is a duplicate hyperref identifier. The conclusion is the same though, we need a full mwe the generates this warning. It can be caused by al sorts of things.

Comment: @André Xavier: You write your problem only disappears, if you delete your equation!!!! Then do not ask a question with this long equation - change it to e.g. `x=2`. I am voting to close, as it is now your question is impossible to answer, and you have made it impossible to help further.

Comment: although this question has already been closed, there *is* one piece of information that can be used to help track down the problem.  the warning message states "destination with the 
same identifier (name{equation.3.2.1}) has been already used".  look for the string "`equation 3.2.1`" in the `.aux` file -- that should appear twice, and from that it might be easier to identify the other use of this string.

Comment: @barbarabeeton this happens because I used `subequations` to define an equation before the one with the warning message and that equation, although have a different label in tex file, appears in the .aux file as the same label as equation.3.3.2, which gives the message in the post. and I don1t know why LaTeX do this!

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have modified the post to include your observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably load `hyperref` before you load `amsmath`. Then `hyperref` does not work correctly with some environements from `amsmath`. To avoid prolems like this,

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

should always come after other `\usepackage` statements.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}   
        \rho(\bm{z}) = \bm{z}; 
        \label{eq.:Rho(z)=z} \\
        \bm{x}(\bm{z}) = \epsilon + (1 - \epsilon){\bm{z}}^p, & \quad \text{for } p \geqslant 1
        \label{eq.:SIMP}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
    \overline{\bm{z}} = \frac{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(\bm{z} - \eta\right)\right)}{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(1 - \eta\right)\right)}
    \label{eq.:HeavisideFnc}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

works correctly, while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% -- BAD! Too early, hyperref should be last
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}   
        \rho(\bm{z}) = \bm{z}; 
        \label{eq.:Rho(z)=z} \\
        \bm{x}(\bm{z}) = \epsilon + (1 - \epsilon){\bm{z}}^p, & \quad \text{for } p \geqslant 1
        \label{eq.:SIMP}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
    \overline{\bm{z}} = \frac{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(\bm{z} - \eta\right)\right)}{\tanh\left(\beta\eta\right) + \tanh\left(\beta\left(1 - \eta\right)\right)}
    \label{eq.:HeavisideFnc}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

leads to the warning you noticed.